# Linux SLAB_CTOR_VERIFY and cache undeclared

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel

I try to compile a program, that serves as a example how storage allocation works.

The compiler gives me a error, that 'cache' and 'SLAB_CTOR_VERIFY' is undeclared.

I can not find the declaration in my whole Kernel project ( Linux Kernel 2.6.32 ).

Maybe there are some replacements or something like that.

I found nothing in the web about that, but maybe some of you can give me a clue.

Here is the Sourcecode:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/completion.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

static int thread_id=0;
static DECLARE_COMPLETION( on_exit );
static kmem_cache_t *cache;

struct linobj {
    int dummy_i, dummy_j, dummy_k;
    char dummy_feld[250];
    wait_queue_head_t wq;
};

static void linobj_destructor(void *objp, kmem_cache_t *cache,
    unsigned long flags)
{
    printk("linobj_destructor( %p )\n", objp);
    return;
}

static void linobj_constructor(void *objp, kmem_cache_t *cache,
       unsigned long flags)
{
    struct linobj *ptr = (struct linobj *)objp;
    if( flags & SLAB_CTOR_VERIFY )
        return;
    printk("linobj_constructor( %p )\n", objp);
    init_waitqueue_head(&ptr->wq);
    return;
}

static int thread_code( void *data )
{
    unsigned long timeout, retvalue;
    int i;
    struct linobj *obj;

    daemonize("linobj-test");
    allow_signal( SIGTERM );
    for( i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
        obj = (struct linobj *)kmem_cache_alloc( cache, GFP_KERNEL );
        printk("objadr=%p\n", obj );
        timeout=HZ;
        retvalue=schedule_timeout_interruptible(timeout);
        kmem_cache_free( cache, obj );
        if( retvalue )
            break;
    }
    complete_and_exit( &on_exit, 0 );
}

static int __init slab_init(void)
{
    cache = kmem_cache_create( "linobj", sizeof(struct linobj),
        0, 0, linobj_constructor, linobj_destructor );
    if( !cache )
        return -EFAULT;
    thread_id=kernel_thread( thread_code, NULL, CLONE_KERNEL );
    if( thread_id==0 ) {
        kmem_cache_destroy( cache );
        return -EIO;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit slab_exit(void)
{
    kill_pid( find_vpid(thread_id), SIGTERM, 1 );
    wait_for_completion( &on_exit );
    if( cache )
        kmem_cache_destroy( cache );
}

module_init( slab_init );
module_exit( slab_exit );

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Thanks in advance

Peter

Answer (score 1):

SLAB_CTOR_VERIFY got removed in [2.6.22](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=50953fe9e00ebbeffa032a565ab2f08312d51a87)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is ther any replacement for it?

Comment: from the changelog I linked: There is a related flag SLAB_CTOR_VERIFY that is frequently checked to be clear in fs inode caches.  Remove the pointless checks (they would even be pointless without removeal of SLAB_DEBUG_INITIAL) from the fs constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to compile with some changes. SLAB.. has been removed, and kmem_cache functions have been changed. `kmem_cache_t` has been replaced with `struct kmem_cache`:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/completion.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/sched.h> // daemonize

static int thread_id=0;
static DECLARE_COMPLETION( on_exit );
typedef struct kmem_cache kmem_cache_t; //
static kmem_cache_t *cache;

struct linobj {
    int dummy_i, dummy_j, dummy_k;
    char dummy_feld[250];
    wait_queue_head_t wq; 
};

static void linobj_destructor(void *objp, kmem_cache_t *cache,
    unsigned long flags)
{
    printk("linobj_destructor( %p )\n", objp);
    return;
}

static void linobj_constructor(void *objp) {
    struct linobj *ptr = (struct linobj *)objp;
    printk("linobj_constructor( %p )\n", objp);
    init_waitqueue_head(&ptr->wq);
    return;
}

static int thread_code( void *data )
{
    unsigned long timeout, retvalue;
    int i;
    struct linobj *obj;

    daemonize("linobj-test");
    allow_signal( SIGTERM );

    for( i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
        obj = (struct linobj *)kmem_cache_alloc( cache, GFP_KERNEL );
        printk("objadr=%p\n", obj );
        timeout=HZ;
        retvalue=schedule_timeout_interruptible(timeout);
        kmem_cache_free( cache, obj );
        if( retvalue )
            break;
    }
    complete_and_exit( &on_exit, 0 );
}

static int __init slab_init(void)
{
    cache = kmem_cache_create( "linobj", sizeof(struct linobj),
          0, 0, linobj_constructor);
    if( !cache )
        return -EFAULT;
    thread_id=kernel_thread( thread_code, NULL, CLONE_KERNEL );
    if( thread_id==0 ) {
        kmem_cache_destroy( cache );
        return -EIO;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit slab_exit(void)
{
    kill_pid( find_vpid(thread_id), SIGTERM, 1 );
    wait_for_completion( &on_exit );
    if( cache )
        kmem_cache_destroy( cache );
}

module_init( slab_init );
module_exit( slab_exit );

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: But I thought I need `if( flags & SLAB_CTOR_VERIFY )` to controll the flags?! Is that not neccessary?